# make formulas as \ttfamily

Tags: math-mode, xetex, typewriter

I am not new to \XeTeX but new with using formulas. For me it would make sense to display the formulas in monotype (`\ttfamily`). Does it make sense to do that? How can I do that?

```
% math.tex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
text \(-1 \leq r \leq +1\) ist zu ende
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you are writing looks more like source code to me in which case you would probably use `verbatim` or something from the `listings` or `minted` packages. If you are writing "real" maths, I would expect `\(-1 \leq r \leq 1\)`, in that case I would say mono-spaced fonts are unusual nowadays. (I'm not even sure if all symbols are even supported, I suspect that will not be the case with the standard fonts.)

Comment: You might be interested in [Math symbols in tt font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119879/35864), [How do I change the standard “math font”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86785/35864), [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/35864)

Comment: It looks like that there is no real solution - there are only a lot of workarounds. And that points me to the thinking that it isn't usual in TeX-world to use monotype fonts for math?

Comment: I would say you are right in thinking that monotype maths is unusual. I think I have seen one or two papers using monospaced maths, but those were probably written well before the advent of TeX. (See also [Can I change all math output to use monospaced text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62978/35864) and [How to change math font to monospace, only inside \texttt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64251/35864))

Comment: Ok, then please morph your comment to an answer. ;)

Comment: @moewe Duplicate, or would you like to answer?